# How to call action using CURL in magento?

Tags: php, magento, curl, magento-1.8

I have to call action using CURL, because of backround process. Below is my code.

```
$url = "http://www.domain.com/index.php/checkout/cart/deleteall";  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$errorMsg = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
echo '<br/>';
echo $errorMsg;
die();
```

Cart Controller action

```
public function deleteallAction()
    {
        $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
        $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();       
        foreach ($items as $item){
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }
        $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
    }
```

I have create deleteallAction in cart controller. But CURL its not working. Its also not give me any error. I have call this in ajax.

Please guide me, if I am wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: $data = curl_exec($ch); $r = curl_getinfo($ch); print_r($r); and check http response status is 200?

Comment: I have tried this. But nothing return.

Comment: can u post ur controller code..have you used a custom controller or modified the core one?

Comment: I have edit question with controller code. I have used custom action. One more thing @huzefam. I am using CURL code in savePaymentAction, which is call by ajax.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, Now its returning http response status 200

Comment: if you are accessing same instance ..why do you need to fire curl..you can directly post data using ajax to you custom action

Comment: then curl is ok try to send response back from your function to check try some echo 'i m in function';

Comment: @huzefam, I have to empty cart items in this action without redirection. Thats why I am trying CURL

Comment: @RakeshSharma, yes its return response but my code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Jimmeh.you need to change action url `http://www.domain.com/index.php/checkout/cart/updatePost` and change action method post

```
<?php
//
// A very simple PHP example that sends a HTTP POST to a remote site
//

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.domain.com/index.php/checkout/cart/updatePost");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "update_cart_action=empty_cart&cart=$quoteId");
// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

As you add new action in `cartcontroller` the for empty cart use code  `$this->_emptyShoppingCart();` to empty cart.

See more at cartcaontollers

```
   public function updatePostAction()
    {
        $updateAction = (string)$this->getRequest()->getParam('update_cart_action');

        switch ($updateAction) {
            case 'empty_cart':
                $this->_emptyShoppingCart();
                break;
            case 'update_qty':
                $this->_updateShoppingCart();
                break;
            default:
                $this->_updateShoppingCart();
        }

        $this->_goBack();
    }
```

How  curl works http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Comment: Actually I want remove cart item. For this I have create deleteallAction. I have tried your code but what is this "&cart%5B1%5D%5Bqty%5D=1" ?

Comment: Problem is that my CURL is not calling. And I need to work with CURL.

Comment: is php curl enable in magento & ihav check the code is it working

Comment: Yes. I am working on local server. I am calling CURL in ajax.